# Explain what is happening in using Newton's method solving $x^3-2x+2=0$ with $x_0=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Compute four steps of Newton's method to solve $x^3-2x+2=0$ with $x_0=0$. Explain what is happening.

What I have so far:
Since $f(x)=x^3-2*x+2$, we  have $f'(x)=3x^2-2$

Applying Newton's method $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^3-2x_n^2+2}{3x_n^2-2}$

Since $x_0=0$, we can get $x_1=1$, $x_2=0$, $x_3=1$, $x_4=0$

I am having trouble explaining what is happening partially because I am not sure what the problem is asking in this latter part. 
My guess is that it is asking me to explain why x here is jumping from 0 to 1 and this may somehow have something to do with the convergence?

Comment: The method is *not* converging. What about the graph of the function is relevant here? Hint: find the critical point(s), classify them with the second derivative test, and use that to get a sketch of the function. (Or get a graph numerically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of the Newton algorithm is to find a sequence that converge to the roots of an equation (to approximate it). Here as your sequence doesn't converge, this is obviously a fail.

Now, you did prove earlier in your lessons (at least I hope so) a theorem that assure that under some hypothesis, the sequence converge : what hypothesis is missing here?

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your comment. It definitely helped me! I'm considering: x=x^3-3x+2=(x-1)(x^2+x-1). This, we can see x=1 is a fixed point. f'(1), however, is 1, which violates the hypothesis that the absolute value of f'(s) where s is a fixed point should be between 0 and 1. (Sorry for the terrible formatting/potential error in calculation as I'm typing in my phone and I mind calculated those things...)

Comment: No, this is not the Newton's method. You're looking for a fixed point of $\phi(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$. A fixed point $a$ of $\phi$ verify $f(a) = 0$. But $\phi'(x) = 1 - \frac{(f'(x))^2 - f(x) f''(x) }{(f'(x))^2} $, so $\phi'(a) = 0$, and the fixed point $a$ is attractive. No, the two problems that may arise are : 1) $f'(a) = 0$, making $\phi$ ill defined 2) You start too far from the fixed point.

Comment: @QiminLiu : Indeed, we only proved that $\phi$ is contractive near $a$. But if you go far enough, "everything is possible". And this is what happens here : you start outside the region of convergence. And this is the big problem  of the Newton method.  See this link to see a nice exemple of what looks like the regions of convergence of the Newton method for the roots of the polynomial $z^3-1$ in $\Bbb C$ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal .

Answer (score 3):

As with any not everywhere contractive fixed point map, the fixed point iteration $x=g(x)$ may converge to a cycle
$$x_{k+1}=g(x_k)\text{ and }x_0=x_n=g(x_{n-1})$$ where $x_k\ne x_0$, $k=1,...,n-1$. This cycle will be stable if
$$
|g'(x_0)|·|g'(x_1)|·…·|g'(x_{n-1})|<1,
$$
which means that starting the iteration close enough to one of the points in the cycle will converge to the cycle.

Here the fixed-point iteration is the Newton method $$g(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\text{ and }g'(x)=-\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2}$$ with $f(x)=x^3−2x+2$, $f'(x)=3x^2-2$, $f''(x)=6x$. It is now easy to verify that $g(0)=1$ and $g(1)=0$. The derivative of this 2-cycleis $0$ as $g'(0)=0$ and $g'(1)=-6$, so indeed it is stable.

---

The graph with tangent lines is (thanks to wikipedia on Newton's method)
[image: function graph]

The Newton fractal with cycle detection (from the corresponding wikipedia article) is

[image: Newton fractal]

where the red regions are initial points converging towards the 0-1-cycle.

Comment: Hi, I just want you to know that I really appreciate your answer. However, Tryss's hint and comments have already helped me to arrive at a similar, if not same, answer as yours. So I adopted his answer. But I really like your answer and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The Newton-Raphson algorithm can fail to converge to a root under certain conditions. The theorem you're referring to is likely the convergence theorem for Newton's method, which states that if certain conditions are met, then the sequence of guesses generated by the method will converge to a root of the equation.

The conditions for convergence are:

The function $f(x)$ must be continuously differentiable in an open interval containing the root. And the derivative $f'(x)$ must be nonzero in the interval containing the root and the initial guess $x_0$ must be sufficiently close to the root.
In the case of the equation $x^3 - 2x + 2 = 0$, the first two conditions are satisfied, as the function is continuously differentiable and the derivative is nonzero near the root. However, the initial guess $x_0 = 0$ is too far away from the root, and so the algorithm fails to converge.
For your problem of $x^3 - 2x + 2 = 0$ with $x_0 = 0$, we have:

$$f(x) = x^3 - 2x + 2$$ with the derivative
$$f'(x) = 3x^2 - 2$$

The first guess is $x_0 = 0$, so we can plug this into the formula to get:

$$x_1 = x_0 - f(x_0)/f'(x_0) = 0 - f(0)/f'(0) = -2/(-2) = 1$$

So the first iteration gives us a new guess of $x_1 = 1$. We can then repeat the process with $x_1$ as the new guess:

$$x_2 = x_1 - f(x_1)/f'(x_1) = 1 - f(1)/f'(1) = 1.1666666666666667$$

We can continue the iterations until we reach a desired level of accuracy or until we see that the sequence of guesses is not converging. In this case, the sequence of guesses converges to the root at around $x = 1.7693$.

If we had chosen a different initial guess that was closer to the root, the algorithm may have converged. For example, if we had chosen $x_0 = 1$, the algorithm would have converged to the root at $x = 1.7693$.